# Python script freez after some time

Tags: python, azure, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake-gen2

- **azure**:
- **5.0.0**:
- **Databricks clusters**: 12.2LTS
- **Python 3**

**Describe problem:** I'm facing problem in my code where I should extract metadata of all files inside containers of ADLS GEN2 and program still running but no returned data after 6 hours this is the code im using

```
    def list_container_metadata(self, skiped_containers, batch_size=1000000):
        containers = self.blob_service_client.list_containers(include_metadata=True)

        for container in containers:
            # skip the processed container
            if container['name'] in skiped_containers:
                print(f"Container  {container['name']}  Already Processed!")
                continue

            print("\nCONTAINER: ", container['name'])
            self.container_client = self.blob_service_client.get_container_client(container['name'])
            blob_list = self.list_blobs()

            container_data = []
            for blob in blob_list:
                container_data.append((
                    self.storage_name,
                    container['name'],
                    blob.name,
                    blob.last_modified,
                    blob.size
                ))
                if len(container_data) % 100000 == 0:
                    print("BATCH SIZE:", len(container_data))

                if len(container_data) % batch_size == 0:
                    yield container_data
                    container_data = []
            # Yield any remaining data
            if container_data:
                yield container_data
            else:
                yield [(self.storage_name, container['name'], "", "", -1)]
```

I'm facing problem in my code where I should extract metadata of all files inside containers of ADLS GEN2 and program still running but no returned data after 6 hours the memory of cluster used 50% and CPU 10%. the cluster/code keep running but I can't see any prints of extracted metadata anymore

Comment: Can you able to list the blobs?  Check time taken to list the blobs using below code.

```start_time = time.time()
   blob_list = self.list_blobs()
end_time = time.time()
listing_time = end_time - start_time
```

Comment: @JayashankarGS Yes Im able to generate list of blobs and in the beginning of the run it run well but after 6h of run the code not able to extract more blobs metadata and the cluster still running I don't know if there is session limit or something but the sdk should raise error about that thing that I don't have in logs !

Answer (score 0):

The possible reason is the listing of blobs and looping through all `10,00,000` for generating data for the blobs having more records than your batch size.

So, if you are getting blob successfully then the problem is in looping. So, try below code

```
def list_container_metadata(self, skiped_containers, batch_size=1000000):
        containers = self.blob_service_client.list_containers(include_metadata=True)

        for container in containers:
            # skip the processed container
            if container['name'] in skiped_containers:
                print(f"Container  {container['name']}  Already Processed!")
                continue

            print("\nCONTAINER: ", container['name'])
            self.container_client = self.blob_service_client.get_container_client(container['name'])
            # Measure the time it takes to list blobs
            start_time = time.time()
            blob_list = list(self.list_blobs())
            end_time = time.time()
            listing_time = end_time - start_time
        
            print(f"Time taken to list blobs in container {container['name']}: {listing_time:.2f} seconds")

            if len(blob_list) > batch_size:
                for i in range(0,len(blob_list),batch_size):
                    tmp = [(self.storage_name,container['name'],i.name,i.last_modified,i.size) for i in blobs[i:i+batch_size]]
                    yield tmp
            else:
                tmp = [(self.storage_name,container['name'],i.name,i.last_modified,i.size) for i in blobs]
                yield tmp
```

Here, looping according to batch size and getting meta data using list comprehension which faster than `for loop`.

And one more thing try giving lesser batch size.

Output:

[image]

I have some few hundreds of blobs I given 40 has batch size. In your case give some 30k-40k.

Comment: what version of SDK are you using because method list_blobs() returns ItemPaged and this type of object has no len implemented

Comment: ok. do `list(return_itempaged)`. That is `list(self.list_blobs())`

Comment: yes but doing it like that will impact the Memory in my case I have containers with +40millions blobs imagine doing list for that, am I missing something ?

Comment: ok. Around  how many containers you have ? Because you can achieve container level parallelism in databricks

Comment: this why in my function I added the batch_size in the first place just to limit number of object loaded to memory

Comment: depends on storage some of them has one container and others with +4 containers

Comment: what you can do is for every storage account  creating `t = sc.parallelize(["list_of_containers"])` then doing `t.rdd.map(above_function)`.
let me see with another approach.

Comment: Have you tried with smaller batch size. In thousands

Comment: yes the problem as I described before is that the job start everything works fine  in the beginning but after 6h of run the code not able to extract more blobs metadata and the cluster still running I don't know if there is session limit or something but the sdk should raise error about that thing that I don't have in logs

Comment: That may be because user sessions automatically timeout after six hours.

Comment: Yeah I wonder if this is the problem but the SDK should raise an error in this case to stop code from running ! and I can't find any documentation about that

Comment: Another approach is running this as a job not as user but as application where timeout configured more than six hours.

Comment: can you please add some references about that

Comment: Yeah I am checking i will update you. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/configurable-token-lifetimes) once.

Comment: and btw in my class im using rbac connection 
credentials = get_authenticated_client(AzureCredentials)
                self.blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url=self.url,
                                                             credential=credentials)

Comment: create a job in databricks using notebook. This may run till end. 
Refer [this](https://docs.databricks.com/en/workflows/jobs/jobs-quickstart.html).

Comment: I already created workflow in databricks to schedule as I told you I'm facing the mentionned problem and actually it works for simple storage with 400k blobs but when it comes to bih storage take so long and in the end stopped extracting metadata from ADLS

Comment: By any chance did you use `timeout_seconds` or `Duration thresholds` for your job. Even that's not working?

Comment: Actually Im not using those parameters !

Comment: Try those parameters setting more than 6-7 hrs.
One more thing i have tried below code in databricks notebook itself, it worked successfully ```import time
print("before 6h")
time.sleep(21600)
print("after 6h")```